# Example selenium project in C#?

Tags: selenium, c#

Does anyone know of a good place to download a selenium project that was written in C#?

I've been doing automation for the past ~1.5 years and i'm interested to see what other people are doing. How they are structuring their projects, managing their tests.  Anyone have good examples of complete projects?

Answer (score 2):

I [searched on Google for "c# example selenium github"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23%20example%20selenium%20github&rct=j) and one result came up, looks like a full project: https://github.com/atosorigin/SeleniumExample

I think github might contain more examples and projects

Answer (score 1):

Github allows you to easilly filter out projects related to selenium and written using C#.

Take a look at this list: https://github.com/search?l=C%23&o=desc&q=selenium&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this implementation in github. The code is written in c# using selenium, web driver. It implements Page object model

https://github.com/sham332/CSharpSelenium

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium tools](https://www.brainbeast.best/faq-about-selenium-webdriver-on-c-sharp-with-examples/) using C#. There are lots of code snippets.